# Making two matrix from one

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix that I would like to split into two separate matrices based on a set of conditions.

The input matrix can be generated with the following code:

```
lbits = 8;
ntags = 10;

k = randi(lbits,1,ntags);
Tag  = zeros(lbits,ntags);

Tag(lbits*(find(k)-1) + k)=1;
TagAnswer = Tag';
```

Which returns:

```
TagAnswer =

     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
```

My conditions are:

1. If place of bit '1' is on position `lbits/2` or higher, add the row to matrix `A`
2. If place of bit '1' is less then position `lbits/2`, add the row to matrix `B`

With the above `TagAnswer` I want the 2nd, 5th and 7th rows to be moved into `B` and the remaining rows moved into matrix `A`

Comment: Please reword your question and provide the desired output from your examples, I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: @excaza I edited. I want to separed this matrix into two new. My condition is position on number '1' in each row. If position of '1' higher or equal than l/2 put into new matrix. If smaller then l/2 put in another matrix

Comment: Please clearly define the input and output. Naming things example1234 is not helpful.

Comment: @excaza Is now better :)

Comment: I'm assuming by `l` you mean the width of `TagAnswer` (which is your *input*, not output)? Doesn't that mean that the ones in rows 1, 2, 5, and 7 are in a position *less than or equal to* `L/2`?

Comment: @richi12 It's clearer now. I've voted to reopen. Jsut one thing: do you mean "on position lbits/2 or higher", or "on position higher than lbits/2"? The result doesn't seem to match your description

Comment: @excaza No 1 is number in TagAnswer. It could be 0 or 1. Could you differentiate position of 1 in rows 1, 2, 5, and 7? Position of 1 in these rows is smaller then 'lbits/2'. In the 3, 4, 6, 8, 9 and 10 row position of 1 is higher or equal then 'lbits/2'

Comment: @richi12 Assuming that there is exactly one `1` in each row, you can do it as follows. `[~, pos] = max(x,[],2); ind = pos>=lbits/2; y1 = TagAnswer(ind,:); y2 = TagAnswer(~ind,:);`. Or change that `>=` to whatever you need; I still don't see it clear

Comment: @richi12 please review my edit and see if my understanding is correct. If yes, I will vote to reopen. If not, I can revert the changes.

Comment: @LuisMendo this is not correct. I just want to move rows where '1' is smaller then lbits/2 (lbits is width of matrix) into new matrix and the rest into another???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming my edit is correct, you can use the `row` and `column` outputs of [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to index `TagAnswer` and pull the rows based on your conditions:

```
% Generate sample data
lbits = 8;
ntags = 10;

k = randi(lbits,1,ntags);
Tag  = zeros(lbits,ntags);

Tag(lbits*(find(k)-1) + k)= 1;
TagAnswer = Tag';

% Find bit locations and distribute rows accordingly
[r, c] = find(TagAnswer);
A = TagAnswer(r(c>=(lbits/2)), :);
B = TagAnswer(r(c<(lbits/2)), :);
```

For my test case I have:

```
TagAnswer =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0



A =

     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1



B =

     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
```

---

Edit: Because MATLAB stores data column-major, `find` also works column-major and will likely lose the row ordering. If it important to preserve the row ordering of `TagAnswer` in `A` and `B` you can use [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) after the `find` call:

```
[r, sortidx] = sort(r);
c = c(sortidx);
```